# Python Pandas data binning

Tags: python, pandas, binning

Apologies for any lack of clarity...I am new to posting here....

I am working with pandas on a data frame, and I would appreciate any input from the community. Here is what the data frame looks like…...see screenshot here

[screenshot of the data frame structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0Eck.png)

my goal is to create an independent data frame that averages x and y into bins separately based on T increments of 5…..

Fore example…..  for T in range 0-5 => average corresponding x, y values into x1bin, y1bin,  then for T in range 5-10 => average corresponding x, y values into x2bin, y2bin……..for T in range 10-15 => average corresponding x, y values into x3bin, y3bin………and increment this all the way to T in tan135-140. In the meanwhile index the data to ID….meaning keep data belonging to ID with ID  one.  As you might have noticed there will be some bins with NAN values because there are corresponding Ts, and that is fine…….

Finally, it might be helpful to know the way I calculated the T…… which happens to be a rolling time of A per ID…….and starts from 0 with every new ID

df[’T’] = df.groupby(['ID’]).A.apply(lambda x: x - x.iloc[0]) / np.timedelta64(1, 'm')

Thank you in advance….

Comment: [please read this post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to structure dataframes on SO. Also post a sample of what you would like your second dataframe to look like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming df as your dataframe

```
t_range = 5
t_ranges = np.arange(0,df['T'].max()+1,t_range)
new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['t_range','x_avg','y_avg'])
for i in range(1,len(t_ranges)):
    a = df[df['T']>=t_ranges[i-1]][df['T']<t_ranges[i]]
    x_avg = a['X'].mean()
    y_avg = a['Y'].mean()
    new_df = new_df.append({'t_range':t_range[i],'x_avg':x_avg,'y_avg:y_avg},ignore_index=True)
```

sample data df

```
    T   X   Y
0   1   2   3
1   2   3   4
2   3   4   5
3   4   5   6
4   5   6   7
5   6   7   8
6   7   8   9
7   8   9   1
```

using t_range = 2

i.e 0-2,2-4,4-6

sample output new_df

```
     t_range  x_avg  y_avg
0      2.0    2.5    3.5
1      4.0    4.5    5.5
2      6.0    6.5    7.5
```

EDIT:
change x_avg and y_avg as given below, they will ignore any NaNs present in the data , t_range = 2 used

```
 x_avg = a['X'].dropna().mean()
 y_avg = a['Y'].dropna().mean()
```

sample data

```
    T   X    Y
 0  1   2.0  6.0
 ---------------- t<2
 1  2   NaN  NaN
 2  3   7.0  8.0
 ----------------  t<4 and t>=2
 3  4   10.0 11.0
 4  5   NaN  14.0
 ----------------  t<6 and t>=4
 5  6   1.0  NaN
 6  7   12.0 13.0
 ----------------   t<8 and t>=6
 7  8   1.0  2.0
```

output

```
    t_range x_avg   y_avg
0   2.0      2.0    6.0
1   4.0      7.0    8.0
2   6.0     10.0    12.5
3   8.0      6.5    13.0
```

I hope this answers your second query in the comment. If you found the answer helpful do mark it Accepted by clicking on the tick mark on the side of this answer

Comment: Thank you so much @Bandi. This is really helpful. One last thing... If instead of averaging, I wanted to sum the Xs and Ys corresponding to that range of T as well as another unique ID ...I would do df.groupby('T').Y.sum().........Secondly, I would like to generage NANs...since in my actual data, T is not continuous and therefore, will have certain rows that do not have Xs and Ys corresponding to that T range ......I think I can get closer to answer with what you already provided..but if you have any suggestions, I will appreciate it. Thanks